# Synchronous Like Programming in NodeJS / Express with Yield

Tags: node.js, express, co

I'm having a really hard time with Node Asynchronous operation (coming from a PHP background).  I know that you can nest callbacks but that can get out of hand really quickly.

Here is a basic example I want to solve synchronously (I know it might be simple to solve asynchronously for this example but I need to know how to do it synchronously for more complicated projects).

This is an express app where i'm trying to count the number of times a coupon has been used:

```
var express = require('express');
var wrap = require('co-express');

app.post('/grab-valid-coupons', wrap(function* (req, res) {
  var validCoupons = [];

  console.log('grabbing coupons');

  var coupons = yield db.collection('Coupons').find({}).toArray();

  coupons.forEach(wrap(function* (coupon, index) {
    console.log(coupon.code, 'CODE');
    var couponUse = 0;
        couponUse += yield db.collection('Rentals').find({coupon: coupon.code}).count();
        couponUse += yield db.collection('Orders').find({coupon: coupon.code}).count();
    console.log(couponUse);
    if(couponUse < coupon.uses) {
      validCoupons.push(coupon);
    }
  }));
res.json(validCoupons);
}));
```

The first yield is working but the part where I try and get the count of everything is causing the entire server to hang.  Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is that while `wrap` allows code inside it to be written in synchronous style `wrap` itself is asynchronous. Worse, it is asynchronous without returning any promises or accepting any callback thus it can ONLY be used as the most top-level asynchronous function. Using wrap inside wrap does not work. Also using wrap inside forEach does not work. It only works for express middleware callback like post.

Comment: @slebetman ok then it looks like generators aren't the way to go in this scenario

Comment: That's the problem with using alternative async handlers like generator based trampoline (that's what co* libraries do) or async-await or promises: you really, REALLY need to understand async code and callbacks first before you can comfortably use them in order to understand what's going on. Otherwise you can't begin to fix bugs in your code. If you are really a PHP programmer then I can't believe you're not familiar with async code. I'm sure you've used `.onclick` and `.onload` before. That's what async is about.

Comment: give some time on `Promise`.

Comment: Since nobody else mentioned it: you can't turn asynchronous code to synchronous. As @slebetman wrote: you really need to fully understand async code and callbacks first. Then tackle promises. And only then you can venture off to generators and async-await.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to send the data or call next, `res.send(validCoupons)` at the end of your function. should do it

Comment: In my question it wasn't there, but in actual code it was as a json object.

Comment: It's returning Promises instead of the count value

Comment: you need to do `find({}).toArray().then(yield)`